# \sqrt(2) in TikZ results in illegal unit of measure

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code snippet below works well on my Mac but under Linux I get the error messages

> "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." 
>   "! Missing number, treated as zero."  
>   ! Package calc Error: `s' invalid at this point."

for line 3 of the example.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9]
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, -4); %works
\draw ({3.5 / sqrt(2)}, {3.5 / sqrt(2)}) -- ({4 / sqrt(2)},{4 / sqrt(2)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: Try putting the braces around the whole formula to protect the parentheses: `({4/sqrt(2)},{4/sqrt(2)})`.

Comment: Which TeX distributions do use use on the mac and Linux machines, resp.?

Comment: @Andrew Stacey  Thank you but changing the brackets (as shown now in the original post) did not solve the problem

Comment: In which case, the answers to Mico's comment are extremely important as on my Linux machine it compiles with no difficulties.  But I'm using the latest TeXLive so that might be significant.

Comment: No, I  work on OS X 10.7 with pgf 2.1 cvs and your code gives an error. The answer is given above. This problem appears in several questions. You can also define variable outside the command like `\pgfmathsetmacro\sqrttwo{sqrt(2)}` with `\draw (3.5 / \sqrttwo, 3.5 / \sqrttwo) -- (4 / \sqrttwo, 4 / \sqrttwo); `. I proceed like this in some packages.

Comment: Package calc error ?  a complete example is necessary with the version of pgf.

Comment: It also work fine with MiKTeX 2.9 / PGF 2.10

Comment: Have you tried 2**(1/2)?

Comment: Have you solved this?  If not, we really do need more information to be able to help you.  If you don't provide it, we'll probably close this as "too localised" or something like that to indicate that in its current form then it is unanswerable.